# What is the pyplot equivalent of seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to convert this barplot:

```
sns.barplot(x='Pclass', y='Survived', data=train_df)
```

using the built-in plot function from Pandas dataframe or pyplot
How can I translate this seaborn barplot into a pyplot bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` plotting functionality:

```
train_df.plot(x='Pclass', y='Survived', kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure `pyplot` (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`):

```
plt.bar(x='Pclass', height='Survived', data=train_df)
```